# Publishing to Gitlab Package Registry with Deploy Tokens

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, package-managers, codefresh

I've created a Codefresh pipeline to deploy an artifact to Gitlab Package Registry. Source code is also in Gitlab.

I'm able to publish my artifact using a Gitlab Personal Access Token, but when I try to do it using a Gitlab Deploy Token, it fails (401 unauthorized error), no matter if I use Codefresh for it or not.

I have defined this using Gradle, to publish to Gitlab Package Registry:

```
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<group_id>/packages/maven"
            credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
                name = "Private-Token"
                value = '<private_token>'
            }
            authentication {
                header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
            }
        }
    }
```

I use the right `<group_id>` and `<private_token>` values, they are changed here for security reasons.

If I provide my Personal Access Token in `<private_token>`, I can publish to Gitlab Package Registry without any problem. But when I use a generated Deploy Token, it fails. Both my Personal Access Token and the Deploy Token have the same name and username (in the case of Deploy Token).

I'm getting a 401 unauthorized error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'mavenJava' to repository 'maven'
   > Could not write to resource 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<group_id>/packages/maven/mypackageroute/mypackage/0.1/mypackage-0.1.jar'.
      > Could not PUT 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<group_id>/packages/maven/mypackageroute/mypackage/0.1/mypackage-0.1.jar'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you very much

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: I finally ended up using a "fake" Gitlab user an its Personal Access Token from Codefresh CI. Something like "CI user".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main issue is that in your Gradle script, you use header-based authentication while instead, you need to use basic authentication.

In order to get gradle publish with deploy tokens to work, you have to use `PasswordCredentials` + `basic(BasicAuthentication)`:

```
repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/packages/maven"
            credentials(PasswordCredentials) {
                username = <username>
                password = <password>
            }
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to set `name` to `"Deploy-Token"` when using a [deploy token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#authenticate-with-a-deploy-token-in-gradle), i.e.

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<group_id>/packages/maven"
        credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
            name = "Deploy-Token"
            value = '<deploy_token>'
        }
        authentication {
            header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
        }
    }
}
```

`Private-Token` is used for personal access tokens, and `Job-Token` for CI access tokens.

Note here that `name` is the name of the header added to the http request and is not related to the name or username of the token itself.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I managed to make it work using a workaround or so, It's been so long since I had this problem. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is actually the missing part! I blame Gitlab docs for this one! as one would assume that they want to use the actual `Deploy Token Username` instead of a fixture string `Deploy-Token`