# Publishing to Gitlab works, but pulling dependency does not

Tags: package, dependency-management, gitlab-api

I have a module that I push to Gitlab Package Registry (successfully) with a deploy token and I use the same deploy token to establish the repository in another project and pull the dependency.
However, while publishing to the Registry worked, pulling the dependency did not.
The deploy token has both, READ_ and WRITE_ access to package registry.
Both project use gradle 8.0.1
Here's my publishing code:

```
def buildDirRelease= "https:<GIT_URL>/api/v4/projects/$project_id/packages/maven"

publishing {
    publications {
        release(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'com.example.package'
            artifactId = 'exampleproject'
            version = '1.0'

            afterEvaluate {
                from components.getByName('release')
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = buildDirRelease
            credentials {
                username "Gitlab Deploy Token"
                password "<DEPLOY_TOKEN>"  // Store in properties file, reference accordingly
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the dependency code:
project build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }

        //Other custom repositories
        maven {
            url = "https:<GIT_URL>/api/v4/projects/${project_id}/packages/maven"
            name = "Gitlab"
            credentials {
                username "Gitlab Deploy Token"
                password "<DEPLOY_TOKEN>"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

app build.gradle:

```
implementation('com.example.package:exampleproject:1.0')
```

I checked package registry. The package is there as com/example/package/exampleproject and the example dependencies to use they display are using
"com.example.package:exampleproject:1.0" as the value. The URLs are also identical.
I also tried using a different AuthenticationHeader (HttpAuthenticationHeader) for the repository in the second project.
I also tried adding @aar at the end of the dependency, but this made no difference either.
But whenever I try to sync the project, it starts downloading exampleproject.pom and then it says "Could not resolve dependency".
There is a pom-file in the package registry as well.
I tried publishing both locally and over the CI. Both worked.

Why does publishing work, but pulling the dependency does not? And more importantly, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This post led me to the solution:
[Publishing to Gitlab Package Registry with Deploy Tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64140813/publishing-to-gitlab-package-registry-with-deploy-tokens)
Apparently, even though Gradle displays PasswordCredentials as type, when you hover over the credentials bracket, you need to explicitly declare it, for Gitlab to let you enter.
So the correct integration of the repository would be:

```
maven {
            url = "https://<GITLAB_URL>/api/v4/projects/${project_id}/packages/maven"
            name = "gitlab-maven"
            credentials(org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.PasswordCredentials) {
                username "Gitlab Token"
                password "<DEPLOY_TOKEN>"
            }
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
        }
```